# Is this identity about floor function true?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

When $a, b, c$ are positive integers, is this identity below is true for all $a, b, c$?

$$\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor\frac ab \right\rfloor}c \right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{\left\lfloor\frac ac \right\rfloor}b \right\rfloor  $$

Comment: Consider adding a tag for a broader subject area to which the question belongs. Some of [these tags](//math.stackexchange.com/tags/ceiling-function/info#h-related-tags) might fit. *(autocomment)*

Comment: Probably not if a = 27 and b = 8 [a/b] =4.  if c = 1.9. the [[a/b]/c] = [4/1.9] = 3.  And [a/c] = 15.  And [[a/c]/8] = [15/8] = 2.

Comment: @fleablood 1.9 is not a positive integer tho

Comment: meh...$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: Sorry, it is floor function not ceiling function.

Comment: Working on Euler 546?

Comment: [[a/b]/c] = [(a/b - r/b)/c] = a/bc - r/bc - q/c. where a = mb + r and (a/bc - r/bc) = nc + q.   [[a/c]/b] = a/bc - t/bc - u/b where a = dc + t and (a/bc - t/bc) = eb + u.  Do r + q/c always equal t + u/b? (same would apply for ceiling.)

Answer (score 5):

Using division with remainder write
 $a=qbc+r$ with $0\le r<bc$ and then write $r=q'b+r'$ with $0\le r'<b$, as well as $r=q''c+r''$ with $0\le r''<c$. So $a=qbc+q'b+r'=qbc+q''c+r''$.
Because $0\le r<bc$ we conclude that $0\le q'<c$ and $0\le q''<b$.
Then 
$$ \left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor}c\right\rfloor=
 \left\lfloor\frac{qc+q'}c\right\rfloor=q$$
and 
$$ \left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac ac\right\rfloor}b\right\rfloor=
 \left\lfloor\frac{qb+q''}c\right\rfloor=q.$$
So indeed
$$\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac ac\right\rfloor}b\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{\left\lfloor\frac ab\right\rfloor}c\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor\frac a{bc}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: I confess that I'm somewhat surprised by this. I would have suspected it to be false. +1.

Comment: @MPW Me too, but the counterexamples kept failing :)

Comment: Yes, that was my experience. I even tried a small spreadsheet with all a,b,c in the range 1-5. Oh well, live and learn.

Comment: In hindsight it makes sense.  Ceiling works as well.  ceiling = q + 1 if r > 0.  I can't tell you how long I struggled without realizing q' < c and q" < b.